# My scene is pink

Tags: animation

So I'm doing a Minecraft animation and everything was fine and I was rendering and then I check on it and see that half the renders are pink and my characters skins are gone I'm just wondering if anyone knows whats going on and how to fix it (I use Mcprep for textures, I used Mineways for the world and I used the black plasma studios rig)

Answer (score 3):

Pink texture means that the texture files are missing. You maybe changed the textures location or they are not accessible anymore.

Use *Find Missing Files* operator in Info > File > External Data as in the image to let blender find the files.

[image]